# Apollo Server vs Apollo-server-express

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-js, express-graphql

I understand that we need `apollo-server-express` if we want to have multiple endpoints or want to serve REST APIs but is there any advantage of using it over `apollo-server` for running a GraphQL server?